# correct typescript type definition for returning a new object with an existing key

Tags: typescript, type-definition

How do I correctly convert this into a single line?

I do want to fetch a property from an object and return a new object with just that property. This is to filter some properties from an object:

```ts
const pick = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K) => obj[prop]
const toObj = <V>(key: string, value: V) => ({ [key]: value })
const select1 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K) => toObj(prop, pick(obj, prop))
// reduce some
const select2 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K) => toObj(prop, obj[prop])
// worked... now a on-liner?
const select3 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K) => ({ [prop]: obj[prop] })
// hmm... computed property must be string...
const select4 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: string) => ({ [prop]: obj[prop] })
// huh? now: implizit any because type '{}'

// explicit version of toObj
// type is: { [key: string]: V }
const toObjExplicit = <V>(key: string, value: V): { [key: string]: V } => ({ [key]: value })
// test if that is okay
const select5 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K) => toObjExplicit(prop, obj[prop])
// yes, now combine
const select6 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K): { [key: string]: O[K] } => toObjExplicit(prop, obj[prop])
// works, try removing the toObj
const select7 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K): { [key: string]: O[K] } => ({ [prop]: obj[prop]})
// why...??? this should be identical, why do I need an extra function
```

The question is, why is typescript unable to use the definition when I use `select7`, while it is identical with `select6` & `toObjExplicit`

Answer (score 0):

`toObjExplicit` defines `key` as `string` which makes compiler happy.

You can do the same using intersection type (`K & string`):

```
const select7 = <O, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, prop: K & string): { [key: string]: O[K] } => ({ [prop]: obj[prop] })
```

Comment: Interestingly the sublime plugin I use to run the typescript annotations tells me this is not okay "Type '{ [x: string]: O[K & string]; } !== { [key: string]: O[K] } "

Comment: But webpack does not complain... still not sure why this is

Comment: @Nox, no errors in [palyground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20select7%20%3D%20%3CO%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20O%3E(obj%3A%20O%2C%20prop%3A%20K%20%26%20string)%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20O%5BK%5D%20%7D%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20%5Bprop%5D%3A%20obj%5Bprop%5D%20%7D)). What version of typescript do you use?